# FlinkKafkaConsumer setting group.id not working properly when consuming

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use flink1.10.0 for a while, and find a weird problem.

I submit same job twice.

```sh
$ flink list -r
28.02.2020 18:04:24 : f9ad14cb86a14c388ed6a146c80988fd : ReadKafkaJob (RUNNING)
28.02.2020 18:07:23 : e05bf26ee986573ffc01af8b1f5d1d59 : ReadKafkaJob (RUNNING)
```

Two jobs have same group.id, but each of them can read data.
Below log show same event consume twice.

```
2020-02-28 18:08:29,600 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.ReadKafkaJob              - eventDo={"id":"odd奇数","value":0.1,"eventTs":1582884509239,"seqNo":0}
2020-02-28 18:08:29,601 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.ReadKafkaJob              - eventDo={"id":"odd奇数","value":0.1,"eventTs":1582884509239,"seqNo":0}
2020-02-28 18:08:34,442 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.ReadKafkaJob              - eventDo={"id":"odd奇数","value":0.5,"eventTs":1582884514437,"seqNo":1}
2020-02-28 18:08:34,442 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.ReadKafkaJob              - eventDo={"id":"odd奇数","value":0.5,"eventTs":1582884514437,"seqNo":1}
2020-02-28 18:08:39,448 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.ReadKafkaJob              - eventDo={"id":"odd奇数","value":0.2,"eventTs":1582884519443,"seqNo":2}
2020-02-28 18:08:39,448 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.ReadKafkaJob              - eventDo={"id":"odd奇数","value":0.2,"eventTs":1582884519443,"seqNo":2}
```

I have set the 'group.id' in code .

```java
String kafkaTopic = params.get("kafka-topic", "flink-test");
String brokers = params.get("brokers", "192.168.0.100:9092");
String groupId = "simple.read.kafka.job";

Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
kafkaProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
kafkaProps.setProperty("group.id", groupId);

FlinkKafkaConsumer<EventDo> kafka = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(kafkaTopic, new EventDeSerializer(), kafkaProps);
```

**So why two clients with same group consume from kafka twice ?**

**Dose FlinkKafkaConsumer has something special implementation?**

UPDATE:

I have made some tests, starts two console consumers and one flink consumer.

If I use kafka-console-consumer to consume like below, client.id=123

```sh
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 192.168.0.100:9092 --topic flink-test --consumer-property group.id=simple.read.kafka.job --consumer-property client.id=123
```

and another consumer with client.id=456

```sh
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 192.168.0.100:9092 --topic flink-test --consumer-property group.id=simple.read.kafka.job --consumer-property client.id=456
```

Then I start flink job in IDEA to consume topic flink.test with group.id="simple.read.kafka.job"

```
20:38:17,107 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer               - [Consumer clientId=cid0931c3, groupId=simple.read.kafka.job] Subscribed to partition(s): flink-test-0
```

I can check connections and find two consumers.

```sh
➜  bin descKafkaConsumerGroup simple.read.kafka.job --members          
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: G1 GC is disabled in this release.

GROUP                 CONSUMER-ID                              HOST            CLIENT-ID       #PARTITIONS     ASSIGNMENT  
simple.read.kafka.job 123-5925201d-a767-4216-acdc-b46f058db0df /192.168.0.100  123             1               flink-test(0)
simple.read.kafka.job 456-01190de7-5d4e-43c1-9cb6-b599c9c69b41 /192.168.0.101  456             0               -
```

**but where is the flink job consumer?**

Two console consumers behave in one group, Flink job consumer behaves in another group.

**UPDATE2**

I have enable checkout. And the whole code like below.

```java
import com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.model.StringDeSerializer;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateBackend;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.CheckpointConfig;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.DiscardingSink;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.UUID;


@Slf4j
public class SimpleReadKafkaJob {

    final static String clientId = "cid" + StringUtils.remove(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), '-').substring(0, 6);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

        String kafkaTopic = params.get("kafka-topic", "flink-test");
        String brokers = params.get("brokers", "192.168.0.100:9092");
        String groupId = "simple.read.kafka.job";

        System.out.printf("Reading kafka topic %s @ %s\n", kafkaTopic, brokers);
        System.out.println();

        Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
        kafkaProps.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
        kafkaProps.setProperty("group.id", groupId);
        kafkaProps.setProperty("client.id", clientId);

        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> kafka = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(kafkaTopic, new StringDeSerializer(), kafkaProps);
        kafka.setStartFromGroupOffsets();
        kafka.setCommitOffsetsOnCheckpoints(true);

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);
        env.enableCheckpointing(20000);
        env.setStateBackend((StateBackend) new FsStateBackend("file:///Users/ym/tmp/checkpoint"));
        env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);


        DataStream<String> dataStream = env.addSource(kafka);
        dataStream.map((MapFunction<String, String>) s -> {
            log.info("message={}", s);
            return s;
        }).addSink(new DiscardingSink<>());

        env.execute(SimpleReadKafkaJob.class.getSimpleName());
    }


}
```

and log like below

```sh
23:00:47,643 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer               - [Consumer clientId=cidb30879, groupId=simple.read.kafka.job] Subscribed to partition(s): flink-test-0
23:00:47,673 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata                             - Cluster ID: LsItbMw1T_SHYQvJMt_6Fw
23:00:47,677 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator  - [Consumer clientId=cidb30879, groupId=simple.read.kafka.job] Discovered group coordinator 192.168.0.100:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
23:01:02,160 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 1 @ 1583420462134 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e.
23:01:02,572 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 1 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e (1236 bytes in 437 ms).
23:01:22,136 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 2 @ 1583420482135 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e.
23:01:22,147 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 2 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e (1236 bytes in 10 ms).
23:01:42,139 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 3 @ 1583420502138 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e.
23:01:42,151 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 3 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e (1236 bytes in 12 ms).
23:02:02,138 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 4 @ 1583420522137 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e.
23:02:02,147 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 4 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e (1236 bytes in 9 ms).
23:02:22,141 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 5 @ 1583420542139 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e.
23:02:22,152 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 5 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e (1236 bytes in 12 ms).
23:02:42,138 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 6 @ 1583420562137 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e.
23:02:42,149 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 6 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e (1236 bytes in 11 ms).
23:03:02,140 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 7 @ 1583420582139 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e.
23:03:02,148 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 7 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e (1236 bytes in 8 ms).
23:03:18,031 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.SimpleReadKafkaJob        - message={seqNo: 1, eventTs: 1583420589670, id: even偶数, value: 2.76}
23:03:22,141 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 8 @ 1583420602141 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e.
23:03:22,152 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 8 for job 4d97a614ef4f928b93c8159f30e9c22e (1236 bytes in 10 ms).
23:03:25,544 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.SimpleReadKafkaJob        - message={seqNo: 2, eventTs: 1583420598370, id: even偶数, value: 5.18}
23:03:33,181 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.SimpleReadKafkaJob        - message={seqNo: 3, eventTs: 1583420605939, id: odd奇数, value: 0.89}
23:03:40,659 INFO  com.stc.sls.stream_process.examples.SimpleReadKafkaJob        - message={seqNo: 4, eventTs: 1583420613564, id: even偶数, value: 9.29}
```

But use kafka-consumer-groups shows **no active members**

```
bin descKafkaConsumerGroup simple.read.kafka.job --members
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: G1 GC is disabled in this release.

Consumer group 'simple.read.kafka.job' has no active members.
```

Answer (score 0):

Flink implements the offset saving mechanism via checkpointing by default. This means that the offsets are saved to Kafka on checkpoint. This way, when the job crashes, You can safely replay the events that haven't been processed completely.

So, when You deploy two jobs, it is completely possible and expected that both will process records as the offsets are saved periodically. There are various possibilities to change this behavior, like for example enabling the auto commit with proper interval. Although, this can have a negative effect on performance or cause the loss of the data on restart.

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, deploy two jobs surely expect both will process records although two jobs with same group.id (as using kafka client API,  only one of kafka consumers in a group can process event). So I suspect Flink Runtime could only create one instance to consume events and then pipeline these events to jobs. And This implementation is reasonable .

Comment: No :) Please read the response carefully, the offsets are commited only on checkpoint and there are two consumers created not one!

Comment: Two consumers with same group.id and different client.id should only receive one message at a time, isn't this Kafka's promise?

Comment: I have updated my post. You will clear what I mean.

Comment: As I said :) It will be only visible when the checkpoint is completed, You may want to read the docs provided above.

Comment: I have read and update post. And I enable checkpoint. but shows "Consumer group 'simple.read.kafka.job' has no active members"。Offset is changing when checkout happen。so What you mean "Visible"? just change offset?

Answer (score 0):

In Flink 1.10, Flink use `FlinkKafkaConsumer` to provide Kafka consume ability.

The `FlinkKafkaConsumer` will consume data use a class called `KafkaFetcher`.

`KafkaConsumerThread`, who did the real consume job, which holded by `KafkaFetcher` as a property, doesn't use the `KafkaConsumer#subscribe()` API, but use `KafkaConsumer#assign()` API instead.

Which means Flink doesn't use the consumer's group functionality of Kafka(if you open checkpoint), but manage the partition offset itself through checkpoint mechanism.

So the `groupid` mechanism will not work in Flink app.